# How to fix syntax to nest functions in mathematica?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I wanted to try to make a rule to do norm squared integrals.  For example, instead of the following:

```
Integrate[ Conjugate[Exp[-\[Beta] Abs[x]]]  Exp[-\[Beta] Abs[x]], 
           {x, -Infinity, Infinity}]
```

I tried creating a function to do so, but require the function to take a function:

```
Clear[complexNorm, g, x] 
complexNorm[ g_[ x_ ] ] := Integrate[ Conjugate[g[x]]  * g[x], 
                                      {x, -Infinity, Infinity}]
v = complexNorm[ Exp[ - \[Beta] Abs[x]]]  // Trace
```

Mathematica doesn't have any trouble doing the first integral, but the final result of the trace when my helper function is used, shows just:

```
complexNorm[E^(-\[Beta] Abs[x])]
```

with no evaluation of the desired integral?

The syntax closely follows an example I found in http://www.mathprogramming-intro.org/download/MathProgrammingIntro.pdf [page 155], but it doesn't work for me.

Comment: I should have probably added some comments on the applicability of that pattern, on that page. The goal of that example was somewhat different though. Whenever I come up with a new version of the book, will make this part more clear.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason why your expression doesn't evaluate to what you expect is because `complexNorm` is expecting a pattern of the form `f_[x_]`. It returned what you put in because it couldn't pattern match what you gave it. If you still want to use your function, you can modify it to the following:

`complexNorm[g_] := Integrate[ Conjugate[g] * g, {x, -Infinity, Infinity}]`

Notice that you're just matching with anything now. Then, you just call it as `complexNorm[expr]`. This requires `expr` to have `x` in it somewhere though, or you'll get all kinds of funny business.

---

Also, can't you just use `Abs[x]^2` for the norm squared? `Abs[x]` usually gives you a result of the form `Sqrt[Conjugate[x] x]`.

That way you can just write:

`complexNorm[g_] := Integrate[Abs[g]^2, {x, -Infinity, Infinity}]`

---

Since you're doing quantum mechanics, you may find the following some nice syntatic sugar to use:

```
\[LeftAngleBracket] f_ \[RightAngleBracket] := 
 Integrate[Abs[f]^2, {x, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}]
```

That way you can write your expectation values exactly as you would expect them.

Comment: Re: the also.  Yes, but I wanted to do the integral of g^* d g next, where d is a second order derivative operator.

Comment: @PeeterJoot: I added a little something extra to the end of my post again. You might find it interesting.